# How to use if else condition in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs,Right now i am getting "cat_name"(category) inside map function(loop), i just want to add condition "if cat_name!="" || cat_name=="pinned" before fetching data
How can i do this,Here is my current code

```
{students.data?.length > 0 &&
 students.data.map((blog) => (
// 
      {blog.cat_name}   // containing category,want to add condition here
       if(blog.cat_name)
           {
                //further code
           }
        else
          {
              // further code
           }
 ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [inline conditional (ternary operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to render one or the other. Note that you can only return one JSX element, that's why you would have to wrap them in a [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) or `div`

```
<>
  {students.data?.length > 0 &&
    students.data.map((blog) => (
      <>
        {blog.cat_name}
        {blog.cat_name ? <>Either</> : <>Or</>}
      </>
    ))}
</>;
```

References: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a ternary condition :

```
{ condition ? a : b }
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_conditional_operator

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just about right. If you want to go with your syntax, arrow function with no return statement, you could use a ternary approach:

```
{students.data?.length > 0 &&
 students.data.map((blog) => (
    <> //fragment needed to wrap more than one node
      {blog.cat_name ? <>Something</> : <>Something else</>}
    </>
 ))}
```

Or you could go with the return statement, in which you would be able to do a "default" if-else statement.

```
{students.data?.length > 0 &&
 students.data.map((blog) => {
       if(blog.cat_name)
           {
                return <>{blog.cat_name} <>anything else you want here</> </>
           }
        else
          {
              return <>{blog.cat_name} <>anything else you want here</> </>
           }
 })}
```